# Puppeteer unable to run on Heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, puppeteer

I deployed an app on heroku, and I added the Puppeteer Heroku buildpack.

After a succesful redeployment, I tried to run it and it fails. Using `heroku logs -t`, I get this error message:

```
2018-09-07T13:16:10.870497+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Failed to launch chrome!
2018-09-07T13:16:10.870512+00:00 app[web.1]: [0907/131610.045486:FATAL:zygote_ho
st_impl_linux.cc(116)] No usable sandbox! Update your kernel or see https://chro
mium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/linux_suid_sandbox_development.
md for more information on developing with the SUID sandbox. If you want to live
 dangerously and need an immediate workaround, you can try using --no-sandbox.
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You should be able to solve this issue by passing the [`--no-sandbox`](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#no-sandbox) and [`--disable-setuid-sandbox`](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#disable-setuid-sandbox) flags to [`puppeteer.launch()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#puppeteerlaunchoptions):

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
  args: [
    '--no-sandbox',
    '--disable-setuid-sandbox',
  ],
});
```

If this does not work, you may want to read the official Puppeteer troubleshooting guide: [Running Puppeteer on Heroku](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md#running-puppeteer-on-heroku).

Comment: Installation of `https://github.com/jontewks/puppeteer-heroku-buildpack` buildpack on Heroku solved the issue.

Comment: Thank you @EugeneKarataev Worked for me by installing the package

Answer (score 83):

Here is what worked for me. First, I clear all my buildpacks and then I added the puppeteer-heroku-buildpack and the heroku/nodejs one:

```
$ heroku buildpacks:clear
$ heroku buildpacks:add --index 1 https://github.com/jontewks/puppeteer-heroku-buildpack
$ heroku buildpacks:add --index 1 heroku/nodejs
```

Then, add the following args to the puppeteer launch function:

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
  'args' : [
    '--no-sandbox',
    '--disable-setuid-sandbox'
  ]
});
```

Finally, deploy it back to Heroku:

```
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "Fixing deployment issue"
$ git push heroku master
```

Comment: https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/jontewks/puppeteer-heroku-buildpack

Comment: does this work on dockerized image pushed to heroku? Do i have to install buildpacks?

Comment: after using the buildpacks , the deploy got stuck. solved it by clearing the build cache. this might help https://help.heroku.com/18PI5RSY/how-do-i-clear-the-build-cache

Comment: i love you man. the '--disable-setuid-sandbox' was missing for me

Comment: In addition to the steps above I had to use the info from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74471504/412036) to fix the subsequent error message about Chrome/Chromium not being found.

Answer (score 6):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55090914/6243352) is fantastic, but in the interests of a minimal, runnable example I thought I'd share my complete code and workflow for getting up and running with a Puppeteer-based web app.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67595949/6243352) for a simple scheduler and a clock process version (although all three approaches can coexist in one app without doing anything special).

#### `package.json`:

```js
{
  "name": "test-puppeteer",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "puppeteer": "^9.1.1"
  }
}
```

#### `Procfile`:

```
web: node index.js
```

#### `index.js`:

```js
const express = require("express");
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

const app = express();
app.set("port", process.env.PORT || 5000);

const browserP = puppeteer.launch({
  args: ["--no-sandbox", "--disable-setuid-sandbox"]
});

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  // FIXME move to a worker task; see https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/node-redis-workers
  let page;
  (async () => {
    page = await (await browserP).newPage();
    await page.setContent(`<p>web running at ${Date()}</p>`);
    res.send(await page.content());
  })()
    .catch(err => res.sendStatus(500))
    .finally(() => page.close())
  ;
});

app.listen(app.get("port"), () => 
  console.log("app running on port", app.get("port"))
);
```

### Set up

1. Install Heroku CLI and create a new app with Node and Puppeteer buildpacks (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55090914/6243352)):

   ```
   heroku create
   heroku buildpacks:add --index 1 https://github.com/jontewks/puppeteer-heroku-buildpack -a cryptic-dawn-48835
   heroku buildpacks:add --index 1 heroku/nodejs -a cryptic-dawn-48835
   ```

   (replace `cryptic-dawn-48835` with your app name)
2. Deploy:

   ```
   git init
   git add .
   git commit -m "initial commit"
   heroku git:remote -a cryptic-dawn-48835
   git push heroku master
   ```
3. Verify that it worked with `curl https://cryptic-dawn-48835.herokuapp.com`. You should see something like

   ```
   <html><head></head><body><p>web running at Wed May 19 2021 02:12:48 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)</p></body></html>
   ```

Comment: excellent solution, worked for me! if you need only add the pack, just run
"heroku buildpacks:add --index 1 https://github.com/jontewks/puppeteer-heroku-buildpack -a your-app-name".
Make a new comit in order to make a new release and that's all!

Answer (score 3):

I have been able to solve the problem installing puppeteer v19.7.2 in Heroku by adding the following file to be base directory of my project: "**.puppeteerrc.cjs**"

```
const {join} = require('path');

/**
 * @type {import("puppeteer").Configuration}
 */
module.exports = {
  // Changes the cache location for Puppeteer.
  cacheDirectory: join(__dirname, '.cache', 'puppeteer'),
};
```

Puppeteer v19 moved the cache directory and what this file does is tell the npm installer to move the cache directory from $HOME/.cache/puppeteer to the `current-working-directory/.cache/puppeteer`.  This file is also read by puppeteer when launched so it knows where to find the cached files.   I have tested this on Heroku22 and worked perfect.  Remember to add **.cache** to your .gitignore.