# Failed to launch the browser process on Heroku

Tags: node.js, api, heroku, deployment, puppeteer

I built an app using as core node, express and sulla (import puppeteer).

Basically I scrape some data and use sulla to send them via whatsapp.
It works fine on local but when I deploy it on heroku I'm faced with this issue :

> Failed to launch the browser
> process!\n[0601/222716.792459:FATAL:zygote_host_impl_linux.cc(116)] No
> usable sandbox! Update your kernel or see
> https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/linux_suid_sandbox_development.md
>
> for more information on developing with the SUID sandbox. If you want
> to live dangerously and need an immediate workaround, you can try
> using --no-sandbox ...... Core file will not be generated.
>
> TROUBLESHOOTING:
> https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md

I've already added the following buildpacks to my heroku app :

```
https://github.com/jontewks/puppeteer-heroku-buildpack.git
heroku/nodejs
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-chromedriver
```

I've seen solutions like https://stackoverflow.com/a/52228855, but I can't apply it since I'm not directly using puppeteer. Or clear heroku caches without success.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Puppeteer unable to run on Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52225461/puppeteer-unable-to-run-on-heroku)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Until you are using the current npm package of sulla unfortunately it won't work for you on Heroku.** As the linked question says, you need to launch puppeteer with `--no-sandbox` (the --disable-setuid-sandbox arg is not mandatory for Heroku):

```js
await puppeteer.launch({ args: ['--no-sandbox'] })
```

**Sulla lacks this arg in the npm package** ([launch](https://github.com/danielcardeenas/sulla/blob/master/src/controllers/browser.ts#L72)) ([current launch config](https://github.com/danielcardeenas/sulla/blob/master/src/config/create-config.ts)) ([not used launch config that would work with Heroku](https://github.com/danielcardeenas/sulla/blob/master/src/config/puppeteer.config.ts)).

It is very good that you've already added the buildpacks, those are needed if puppeteer is running as a dependency in the background.

**I.)** You could try a fork of sulla, called **sulla-hotfix:** https://www.npmjs.com/package/@jprustv/sulla-hotfix if it suits your needs. This one [still uses](https://github.com/zi9o/sulla/blob/master/src/controllers/browser.ts) the [previous sulla puppeteer config](https://github.com/zi9o/sulla/blob/master/src/config/puppeteer.config.ts), which apparently contains `--no-sandbox` launch arg.

It is true for the original project sulla was forked from: [@open-wa/wa-automate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@open-wa/wa-automate). It may works on Heroku with the buildpacks.

**II.)** Or you could publish a modified version of sulla under MIT license, containing the right launch parameter.

Comment: Thanks !! At some point I managed to make it run with another webpack i've added, think it was chrome just to come back 2 days later with sulla having a major bug... I've since switch to  @open-wa/wa-automate.

Comment: Great, I am glad it runs.