# Puppeteer on Heroku: Failed to launch the browser process

Tags: heroku, puppeteer

I'm using Puppeteer on Heroku and I receive the following error:

```
Failed to launch the browser process! /usr/src/app/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-756035/chrome-linux/chrome: error while loading shared libraries: libX11-xcb.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory TROUBLESHOOTING: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md
```

Comment: Did you go to the troubleshooting link and read the Heroku section?

Comment: Related: [Error: Failed to launch the browser process puppeteer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59979188/error-failed-to-launch-the-browser-process-puppeteer)

Comment: Also: [Puppeteer unable to run on Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52225461/puppeteer-unable-to-run-on-heroku)

Answer (score 22):

1. Declare browser as:

   ```
   const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
                     headless: true,
                     args: ['--no-sandbox','--disable-setuid-sandbox']
                   })
   ```
2. Install `heroku buildpack` [puppeteer heroku buildpack](https://github.com/jontewks/puppeteer-heroku-buildpack)
3. Must clear heroku cache
4. `git add .`
5. `git commit -m "some  text"`
6. `git push heroku master`

Comment: Also pupeteer buildpack should be placed BELOW nodejs buildback:
- nodejs
- pupeteer

Answer (score 5):

May be this could help (copied from Puppeteer official website)

Running Puppeteer on Heroku (https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/troubleshooting.md#running-puppeteer-on-heroku)

Running Puppeteer on Heroku requires some additional dependencies that aren't included on the Linux box that Heroku spins up for you. To add the dependencies on deploy, add the Puppeteer Heroku buildpack to the list of buildpacks for your app under Settings > Buildpacks.

The url for the buildpack is https://github.com/jontewks/puppeteer-heroku-buildpack

Ensure that you're using '--no-sandbox' mode when launching Puppeteer. This can be done by passing it as an argument to your .launch() call: puppeteer.launch({ args: ['--no-sandbox'] });.

When you click add buildpack, simply paste that url into the input, and click save. On the next deploy, your app will also install the dependencies that Puppeteer needs to run.

If you need to render Chinese, Japanese, or Korean characters you may need to use a buildpack with additional font files like https://github.com/CoffeeAndCode/puppeteer-heroku-buildpack

There's also another simple guide from @timleland that includes a sample project: https://timleland.com/headless-chrome-on-heroku/.

Answer (score 2):

Adding this github repo to my heroku buildpack worked for me

https://github.com/jontewks/puppeteer-heroku-buildpack
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You cant run Puppeteer on Heroku with headless: false because it doesn't have GUI to show.

You need to use headless: true that's because it's running on a Linux without GUI

If you have another errors, you may want to read the official Puppeteer troubleshooting guide: [Running Puppeteer on Heroku.](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/troubleshooting.md#running-puppeteer-on-heroku)

Comment: There is no need to include the headless option because by default, the headless option does not spin up the browser which is the required behaviour in production