# Puppeteer via npm package not working in Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, npm, puppeteer

I've seen a few other questions similar to mine (this [Puppeteer unable to run on heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52225461/puppeteer-unable-to-run-on-heroku) was helpful) but it doesn't quite solve my problem. I'm using the Markup's Blacklight npm package in a site of mine running on Heroku. When running locally it works perfectly, but on Heroku it doesn't work because a function in that package is what calls Puppeteer so I cannot add these arguments, although I know `'--no-sandbox'` is an arg.

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
  args: [
    '--no-sandbox',
    '--disable-setuid-sandbox',
  ],
});
```

I'm not getting any outright failures, but it tells me my `browser = null` and I know the data produced is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Could you run the following commands to double check that Google Chrome is properly installed on your Heroku server?

```sh
$ heroku run bash --app your-app
$ google-chrome --version
```

If not, then you can use this [buildpack](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-google-chrome) to download and install Chrome on your Heroku.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem. Both adding the buildpack

`$ heroku buildpacks:add --index 1 https://github.com/jontewks/puppeteer-heroku-buildpack`

and specifying the device to emulate fixed my issue.