# "Could not find Chromium" with Puppeteer on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, deployment, puppeteer, chromium

I'm trying to deploy a nodeJs app using puppeteer on heroku and always getting "Could not find Chromium"

I added the flags

```
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: true,
        args: ['--no-sandbox','--disable-setuid-sandbox'],
    });
```

[I also added the buildpack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O24gP.png)

[And I still get this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nvqwN.png)

Would really appreciate any help

Have a nice day

Comment: this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52225461/puppeteer-unable-to-run-on-heroku

Comment: @RobyCigar Already done : added flags, buildpack and still getting the same error

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.